# Scanning DeTagtive Tag2 beacon

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried scanning **deTAGtive Tag2 beacons** Using **android BLE** scan. But I am not getting UUID in response. I attached the beacon image , Please help with a solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0BEj.jpg

Comment: Can you please explain how a barcode scanning library like ZXing is supposed to read a Bluetooth based device.

Comment: Each deTagctiveTag2 contains a QR code on it. And actually we can get this UUID by Bluetooth scanning as well as through scanning the QR code. I tested in both the ways but didn't get any positive results. If you know to do this through Bluetooth scanning just share your code.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to scan and include a sample image. Note that a QR code could be smaller/fuzzier than what ZXing currently allows if you are using consumer hardware.

Comment: Please check the image

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your goal. The QR code just has the company url along with the device ID (serial number). The device uses Bluetooth Low Energy and it sounds like you can read it over Bluetooth Low Energy. Are you trying to get the internal data like acceleration/temperature etc.? Have you asked the manufacturer for a SDK?

Comment: manufacturer don't have any sdk for this. If you wish to know more about this please go through this url http://www.detagtive.com/en

Comment: I've visited the site. You'll need to ask the manufacturer for a SDK or reverse engineer getting the data yourself. Good luck.